# How to use IIgs enhanced graphics modes in AppleSoft BASIC with System 6?

Tags: graphics, programming, hard-disk, applesoft-basic, apple-iigs

There are many packages that let you use the enhanced graphics modes of the IIgs in AppleSoft BASIC. However most packages like [Iconix](http://whatisthe2gs.apple2.org.za/iconix) do not like [System 6](http://whatisthe2gs.apple2.org.za/system-6-0-1) so they have to run off disks and not the hard drive. AppleSoft's built in graphics are quite inferior to the 320x200 and 640x200 modes the IIgs can use. 3200 color mode would be terrific for programming, but [320x200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_16-bit_computer_hardware_palettes#Apple_IIgs) with a 16 color pallet and 640x200 dithered mode are fine.

The final result should be a BASIC program launched from the Finder under System 6 with access to IIgs graphics and not restricted to running from ProDOS. I want a stable approach to graphics in AppleSoft that allows me to focus on the programming. I have a [MicroDrive IDE](http://whatisthe2gs.apple2.org.za/microdrive-ide) and want to launch BASIC programs from my hard disk using System 6.0.4.  What package can I use to program in AppleSoft with enhanced graphics and use my hard drive to boot System 6?

Comment: Presumably you're returning to ProDOS 8 to run Applesoft programs, so I'm not sure why the GS/OS version matters. (I don't know what Iconix does.) At one point I tried a [simple approach](https://fadden.com/apple2/misc.html#amperqd) of just using the toolbox calls from P8, which worked... mostly. Taking a step back, what are you hoping to accomplish? What do you need the package to do?

Comment: Does your package run on System 6?

Comment: I don't think AmperQD gets along well with *any* version of GS/OS. :-) You're really not supposed to use the IIgs toolbox functions that way. Going by the requirements in your updated question, I'd say it's the wrong approach. I think you will need something that does it all directly, e.g. hits the softswitches to turn the graphics on and does its own rendering.

Comment: Have you considered using GSoft instead of AppleSoft?

Comment: Would anyone consider converting their comment to an answer?